# How can I disable the Rogers NetComm Rocket Hub Firewall which blocks almost every port

Tags: lan, ports

For some reason my Rocket Hub blocks almost every port except for some of the more commonly used ones like 443, 80, 22, 21, 20, etc.

I can run my local LAMP server on my desktop and access it from my laptop, however when I try to use synergy or connect to a Minecraft server over LAN, I am prevented from doing so. I can access the Minecraft server when I am using the server computer, even using the IP given by the Rocket Hub rather than localhost; but when I try to connect to it through anything else on LAN, I am prevented from doing so.

I strongly believe this is an issue with the Rogers Rocket Hub since I did not have issues before the Rocket Hub. I also have tried adding the specific ports to the NAT Port Forwarding settings but still no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the issue. The issue is not the router's firewall, it is my virus scanner's firewall - Vipre Antivirus.

I realised this was the issue after trying to start my Minecraft server in Ubuntu, and it worked. The reason why I never had this issue before is because before I got the rocket hub, I hosted the LAN server on Ubuntu.

To anyone who is looking to find a fix, open Vipre Antivirus click on Edit Settings beside Firewall, Click on exceptions, then go to the Ports tab and add the exception for the specific port. In this case, the Minecraft port is 25565 and uses the TCP protocol. Select the exe file for the Minecraft server and you should be fine. If it still doesn't work, you can just temporarily disable the firewall when you want to run the server until you find a fix.